# MySQL create row error with php/laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to create a new row in 'my_groups' table, but am getting this error:

```xml
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 
1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(mefirst.my_groups, CONSTRAINT my_groups_owner_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES users (id) 
ON DELETE CASCADE) 
(SQL: insert into my_groups (updated_at, created_at) values (2021-05-17 19:07:54, 2021-05-17 19:07:54))
```

Here is my schema:

```php
Schema::create('my_groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('groupName')->default('group');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('owner_id');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('owner_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Here is my MyGroup model where I am creating the row and getting the error:

```php
protected $fillable = [
    'groupName',
    'owner_id'
];

public static function add(User $user) {
    $groupData = array('my group', $user->id);
    Self::create($groupData);
    return "success";
}
```

I have no idea why this is happening and I have confirmed the value of 'owner_id' does exist in my users table as many other solutions have suggested.

Comment: Obviously, you'd first had to insert the user with the corresponding `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `$groupData = array('my group', $user->id);` is the problem.

`array('my group', $user->id);` is the same as `['my group', $user->id]`. There are no keys here. If you dumped `$groupData` you'd get something like this.

```xml
array (
  0 => 'my group',
  1 => $user->id
)
```

When using `create()`, eloquent uses the keys to know which columns to fill. In this case, it's trying to fill the column `'0'` with the `'my group'` value and the column `'1'` with `$user->id`.

`'0'` and `'1'` are not in your `$fillable` properties, which is why the resulting SQL (last line in your error) only seems to be inserting timestamps.

But even if `'0'` and `'1'` were in your `$fillable` properties, SQL would throw another error about the table `my_groups` having no such columns.

---

**To fix this, simply add keys to your `$groupData` array.**

```php
$groupData = [
    'groupName' => 'my group',
    'owner_id'  => $user->id
];
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I missed that.